# sending variable,which is read by arduino, to php script(electronic toll collection system)

Tags: php, arduino

I am building electronic toll colection system using arduino which rfid based;i want to send the "unique id" of the tag(read by arduino) to php script(stored on local apache server root folder).i have written the code please point out the mistakes and also have a look on the ethernet settings whether they are correct in the program..

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
EthernetServer server(80);
byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,4);
EthernetClient client;
int  val = 0; 
char code[10]; 
int bytesread = 0; 
void setup() 
{ 
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
Serial.begin(9600); 
pinMode(2,OUTPUT);   
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);                 
}  

 void loop() <br>
{ 
 if(Serial.available() > 0) {          
    if((val = Serial.read()) == 10) {   
      bytesread = 0; 
      while(bytesread<10) {             
        if( Serial.available() > 0) { 
          val = Serial.read();
          if((val == 10)||(val == 13)) {  
            break;                       
          } 
          code[bytesread] = val;               
          bytesread++;                   
        }
      } 
      if(bytesread == 10) {             
       client.print("GET try.php?code=");
      client.print(code);

client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: localhost");  
client.println();        
      } 
      bytesread = 0; <br>
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);                  
           delay(1500);                       
           digitalWrite(2, HIGH);                  // Activate the RFID reader
    } 
  } 
}
the php script:

<?php   
$variable = $_GET['code']
echo  "code is  $variable ";
?>
```

Comment: ??? where did you get `$_GET['temp']` from when your variable name is `code` from `"GET try.php?code="`

Comment: my mistake...sorry i have edited the code; have a look

Comment: your code is still wrong .... `cde` instead of `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're missing a "client.connect(...)" to connect to your PHP server before sending it an HTTP request :

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetClient

Comment: @Nikhil You're in the right way, you must inspect this error. Can you share it ?

Comment: when i try to execute the reference code which u have suggested in the link it works;but when i make changes in my own code..then it doesn't, nw i m having a doubt whether this will on localhost

Comment: Yeah you should "connect" to your HTTP server, do you have its hostname or IP ?

Comment: after several unsuccessful attempts with localhost;i gave up and now I am using domainname hope it works

Comment: @Nikhil "localhost" for your arduino is your arduino, I'm sure your HTTP server is not on your arduino, so it can't work connecting to localhost.

Comment: @ julien Palard; i have already implemented this code and it working;i didnt go for 127.0.0.1; instead i went for the ipaddress of the (apache)server which was accessible in LAN

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to connect your EthernetClient to the server! Take a look at the Arduino [documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetClient).

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
    client.println();
} else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
}
```

In your example you have to write:

```
Serial.println("connected");
client.print("GET /try?code=");
client.print(code);
client.print(" HTTP/1.0");
client.println();
```

---

EDIT: Here's a complete example:

Replace

```
client.print("GET try.php?code=");
client.print(code);
client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: localhost");
client.println();
```

with

```
if (client.connect(serverIP, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.print("GET /try?code=");
    client.print(code);
    client.print(" HTTP/1.0");
    client.println();
} else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
}
```

and add this to the declarations

```
byte serverIP[] = { 127, 0, 0, 1 }; //That's localhost. Change it to whatever you need!
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but when i try to do that i get an error

Comment: Did you looked up the link? You have to give the connect-function a server as byte array not as EthernetServer. Therefore you have to change the variable to an byte array like {127,0,0,1} or whatever you want and don't give it your EthernetServer-variable!
Look at the example given here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConnect

Comment: problem solved..i had to configure my server..thank you HowUpDoHighKnee to advise me to look back @ arduino documentation